# Does 'per process' also count towards shared libs / dylibs?

Tags: linux, macos, timer, process

I want to use the [`alarm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) function to have an interrupt to arrange for a timeout on a blocking call to `fcntl` + `F_SETLKW` (for lock file acquisition).  However, my code lives in a shared library / dylib (a plugin for a host app), and the docu for `alarm` states that these timers are per-process.

Am I correct to conclude that using `alarm` from a shared lib / dylib might interfere with the host app if it itself also uses the timer or `sleep` or... as well?  And what about other so's / dylibs loaded into the same host process?  (I'm creating a whole suite of different plugins, so they would also all interfere with each other when more than one is loaded at the same time, right?)

Is this generally true -- i.e. if the man states something is per-process, is it thus also shared with all loaded so's/dylibs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since the libraries are loaded to the process and are running in its' context.

Comment: A pity... but it is what it is I guess.  It seems like there's quite a lot of these functions/states/objects that are single-instance + per-process, making life hard for plugin developers?  In my above post, with fcntl file locks there's 1 lock per inode per process, and trying to wait on these locks requires the alarm signal, which does come in 3 flavors but of which there is also only 1 per process.  Do Linux and Mac apps just not use a plugin setup very often, or am I lacking in my knowledge here of what system functions I could better use?  (prob. the latter :) )